# jsonlite::stream_in throwing error in R Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE

Tags: r, jsonlite

It was all working fine but then suddenly one day I started getting this error. I've a json field in DB table and i'm trying to parse it

```
ahoy_prop <- jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(ahoy_events_acc$properties, encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

But its showing this error now -

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without an example text, but here's a way to find which of the elements is causing a parsing problem.

```r
vec <- c('{"a":[1],"b":[2,3]}', '{', '')
out <- lapply(vec, function(z) try(jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(z, encoding="UTF-8")), silent=TRUE))
#  Imported 1 records. Simplifying...
#  Imported 0 records. Simplifying...

which(sapply(out, inherits, "try-error"))
# [1] 2
vec[2]
# [1] "{"
```

Comment: I did that 
```
ahoy_prop <- lapply(ahoy_events_acc$properties, function(z) try(jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(z, encoding = "UTF-8")), silent=TRUE))
```

And strangely it didn't show any error but when I'm counting the rows and columns it coming null but when I'm looking at dataframe its showing a large list

Comment: `try(..., silent=TRUE)` specifically hides the error. Are you saying that `which(sapply(ahoy_prop, inherits, "try-error"))` returns `logical(0)`?

Comment: btw, for formatting, triple backticks (`\`\`\``) only do something special in questions/answers, not in comments. The only thing you can do in comments is use *inline code*, with single backticks. For example, my `try(..., silent=TRUE)` is typed in as `\`try(..., silent=TRUE)\`` :-)

Comment: I tried that and when I run which(sapply(ahoy_prop, inherits, "try-error")), it shows
integer(0)

Comment: To me, that suggests that your input is broken and/or not what you think. I can't really help with that since your question is not reproducible. It works with my data, so I believe the premise works. Please read suggestions on how to make a question reproducible: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info (and then please edit your question). Thanks!